# Xlsxwriter order worksheets with a specified order

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I would like to order my worksheets in a specific order (not alphabetical). In the past I have used Pandas DataFrame that was followed by a list.

```
DataFrame(csv_dict_list)[self.ORDER_LIST]
```

Right now I have to use the workbook and worksheet methods to create my worksheets. I have found out that you can call all worksheets by using workbook.worksheets() or worksbook.worksheets_objs() but I can't use a list there. Only lamba (I think) like this

```
workbook.worksheets_objs.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)
```

Comment: so why does your lambda function not work?

Comment: The lamba does work but it's an alphabetical order. I want to specify the order with for example a list.

Comment: Use a different function, like this : `lambda x: sheetlist.index(x.name)`

Comment: I'm assuming it's getting the index from my list and using that as the order value? I'm not really good with lambdas.

Comment: @alpha1554 Thanks, that was easier than I actually expected. Gonna have to study the lambdas a bit again. You can use your comment as the answer otherwise I'll do it later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a different lambda function, like this : `lambda x: sheetlist.index(x.name)`. Lambdas inherit the scope in which they are called, so they can reference lists that are created in their 'parent' scope.